# How to setimage for an Imageview in a popup dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-popupwindow

This is my `Popup` class,

```
public class Popup {

    public void showDialog(Activity activity, String url){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_playerstats);

        ImageView imageFirst= (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.img_First);

        ImageView dialogButton = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

And my onClick method of Fragment is,

```
public void onClick(final View v) {
    Popup alert = new Popup();
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            alert.showDialog(getActivity(),url);
            break;
        case R.id.button_2:
            alert.showDialog(getActivity(),url1);
            break;
        default:
            // some code here
            break;
    }
 }
```

I need to use the String variable `url` or `url1` and setimage on ImageView `imageFirst`.

Help how could I do this?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the **[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)** dependency to your **`build.gradle`** Section.

```
dependencies {
    // glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

**Then**

```
ImageView imageFirst= (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.img_First);
Glide.with(activity).load(url)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageFirst);
```

Answer (score 0):

add following in `dependencies`

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

and use to set in ImageView

```
Glide.with(mContext)
                        .load(url)
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .dontAnimate()
                        .placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.mipmap.ocassion_placeholder))
                        .into(imageFirst);
```

Answer (score 0):

add dependency in build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Extend your popup class with Dialog

```
public class Popup extends Dialog{

private Context mContext;
private  ImageView imageFirst;
private String url;

public Popup(Context context, String url) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    this.url = url;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.popup_playerstats);

    imageFirst= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_First);
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(url)
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .into(imageFirst);


    ImageView dialogButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.close);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
}
```

In your activity, onClickEvent

```
public void onClick(final View v) {
    Popup popup;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            popup = new Popup(mContext, url);
            break;
        case R.id.button_2:
            popup = new Popup(mContext, url1);
            break;
        default:
            // some code here
            break;
        popup.setCancelable(false);
        popup.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another variable to pass into showDialog method to pass the image's location id from the onClick method. Then in the showDialog method, use this id to set it as an image resource.

onClick:

```
public void onClick(final View v) {
    Popup alert = new Popup();

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            alert.showDialog(getActivity(),url,R.drawable.img1);
            break;
        case R.id.button_2:
            alert.showDialog(getActivity(),url1,R.drawable.img2);
            break;
        default:
            // some code here
            break;
    }
 }
```

showDialog:

```
public class Popup {

    public void showDialog(Activity activity, String url, int id){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_playerstats);

        ImageView imageFirst= (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.img_First);
        imageFirst.setImageResource(id);

        ImageView dialogButton = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }
}
```